# drupal combine account and profile

Tags: drupal, profile, account

Can any one suggest simple code snippet for **combining account and profile tabs** in drupal 6. i'm using ***onepageprofile*** module it works fine but any other simple solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky. If you have groups defined in the Profile module, like About Me, Address Information, etc example categories, they show up as tabs in the $tabs2 array of the theme template.

The obvious solution is to not group fields at all, but this could make the user edit/registration form very large and vertical.

Answer (score 1):

you need to comment line number 567 and 568 in profile.module but this is hack.

This how it is.

```
function _profile_get_fields($category, $register = FALSE) {
  $args = array();
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM {profile_fields} WHERE ';
  $filters = array();
  if ($register) {
    $filters[] = 'register = 1';
  }
  else {
    // Use LOWER('%s') instead of PHP's strtolower() to avoid UTF-8 conversion issues.
    //$filters[] = "LOWER(category) = LOWER('%s')";
    //$args[] = $category;
  }
  if (!user_access('administer users')) {
    $filters[] = 'visibility != %d';
    $args[] = PROFILE_HIDDEN;
  }
  $sql .= implode(' AND ', $filters);
  $sql .= ' ORDER BY category, weight';
  return db_query($sql, $args);
}
```